# proving that dirichlet series has non negative coefficients and does not converge for all $s\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

given $Z(s)=\zeta^2(s)\zeta(s+it)\zeta(s-it)$ I need to prove that Z(s) is represented by a dirichlet series with non negative coefficients whiche does not converge for all $s\in\mathbb{C}$.
I have tried to use the dirichlet convolution formula but I didn't know how to continue with what I got.

Comment: Show that the logarithmic series has non negative coefficients using the product representation and the logarithm power series; exponentiation sends positive coefficients series to positive coefficients series etc; for point two, use the fact that a series of non negative numbers diverges if a subseries does so and find a geometric subseries (eg $n=2^k, s=x$ real, which you can easily compute and show it diverges

Comment: @Conrad thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the well known Euler product formula for $\zeta(s)$, we have

$$
\log\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}{a_n\over n^s}
$$

where $a_n=\begin{cases}1/k & n=p^k,p\text{ prime} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. This suggests that

\begin{aligned}
\log Z(s)
&=2\log\zeta(s)+\log\zeta(s+it)+\log\zeta(s-it) \\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}{a_n\over n^s}[2+n^{-it}+n^{it}]=\sum_{n\ge1}{a_n\over n^s}[2+2\cos(t\log n)]:=\sum_{n\ge1}{b_n\over n^s}
\end{aligned}

This suggests that the Dirichlet series coefficient for $\log Z(s)$ is nonnegative provided that $t$ is real. Now, using the fact that

$$
e^z=\sum_{n\ge0}{z^n\over n!}
$$

we see that the Dirichlet series coefficient for $Z(s)$ is also nonnegative.